# How do you say "woke" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, coloquialismos, neologismos, jerga-política

In English, at least in the United States, a lot of people have started using the word "[**woke**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woke)" to mean

> **alert to injustice in society, especially racism**

After doing a little bit of research, I realize this secondary, less literal meaning of "woke" has actually been used in American English for some time now but has recently resurfaced in common usage.  Regardless, is there any single word in Spanish that conveys this same thing?  I know that a literal translation of "woke" would be "despertado," but does "despertado" carry with it this additional meaning as it does in English (at least American English)?

---

**¿Cómo se dice "woke" en español?**

En inglés, al menos en los Estados Unidos, mucha gente ha empezado a usar la palabra "[**woke**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woke)" para significar

> **alerta a la injusticia en la sociedad, especialmente al racismo**

Después de investigar un poco, me doy cuenta de que este significado secundario, menos literal, de "despertado" se ha utilizado en el inglés americano desde hace algún tiempo, pero recientemente ha resurgido en el uso común. De todas formas, ¿hay alguna palabra en español que transmita lo mismo? Sé que una traducción literal de "woke" sería "despertado", pero ¿"despertado" lleva consigo este significado adicional como lo hace en el inglés (al menos en el inglés americano)?

---

*Para ahorrar tiempo, traducción realizada, en parte, con la versión gratuita del traductor [www.DeepL.com/Translator.](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator.)*

Comment: I think the literal translation would be *[despierto](https://dle.rae.es/despierto?m=form)* (adjective) instead of *despertado* (past participle). But that is, as you say, too literal, and brazofuerte's suggestion "concienciado" works much better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> #### woke (wok)
>
> <sup>`ADJECTIVE`</sup>
>
> 1. (slang) (general) (United States)
>
>    1. **concientizado** (Latin America)
>       I don't have time for people who are negative. I want to be surrounded by people who are woke and who want to change the world. — *No tengo tiempos para personas negativas. Quiero estar rodeado de personas que sean concientizadas y que quieren cambiar el mundo.*
>    2. **concienciado** (Spain)
>       I may not be the most woke person ever, but I'm trying to learn more about the inequality that exists in our society. — *No seré la persona más concienciada del mundo, pero estoy tratando de aprender más sobre la desigualdad que existe en nuestra sociedad.*

- https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/woke

Comment: Actually, in Latin America people will say "estén concientizados" (estar concientizado), because "ser concientizado" refers to the action or process of becoming conscious or aware of something through the agency of somebody else (passive voice). With "ser", we use "consciente", which means "conscientious".

Comment: Great answer!  ¡Gracias!